# Re-order group chart same as the input

Tags: r

I have an input data and i would like to create a grouped chart, but when I finish the creation the problem is the order is different from the input, it arranged it as alphabetical, plus I would like to change the font style to italic, for the species names only.

```
> data <- read.table(
+ text = "Superfamily Drom Bactria Feru Paos
+ ERV 294  224  206  202
+ ERVL-MaLR 103 108 184 231
+ Gypsy 274 187 413 215
+ Pao 6 2 7 4
+ DIRS/Ngaro 15 14 45 25
+ Unknown 26 23 23 37
+ Undefined 76 77 80 95",
+ header = TRUE
+ )
> data
  Superfamily          Drom        Bactria  Feru    Paos
1         ERV           294          224     206     202
2   ERVL-MaLR           103          108     184     231
3       Gypsy           274          187     413     215
4         Pao             6            2       7       4
5  DIRS/Ngaro            15           14      45      25
6     Unknown            26           23      23      37
7   Undefined            76           77      80      95
> data_long <- gather(data,
+ key = "Species",
+ value = "Distrubution",
+ -Superfamily)


> ggplot(data_long, aes(fill=Superfamily, y=Distrubution, x=Species)) + geom_bar(position="dodge2", stat="identity")
```

I would like to build the chart as the same as the input order, and italic font style to the species name only ex ( Drom Bactria ....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're asking for

```
data_long$Species <- factor(data_long$Species, levels = unique(data_long$Species))

ggplot(data_long, aes(fill=Superfamily, y=Distrubution, x=Species)) + geom_bar(position="dodge2", stat="identity") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face = "italic"))
```

If ggplot recieves a factor, it will use the level-order as the axis order.
When it comes to the fonts, you change that in the theme argument.

--edit--

To get the superfamily in the same order as input, you would have to create a factor as we did with the species-name.

```
data_long$Superfamily<- factor(data_long$Superfamily, levels = data$Superfamily)
```

Forgoing the use of the readxl-package to read the excel sheet into R, this should work to change the species name:

```
colnames(data)[2:5] <- c("Alpha Drom", "Beta Bactria", "Gamma Feru", "Delta Paos")
```

Add this line before you create data_long.

Comment: You need to add it after you have created the data_long frame.

Comment: thank you so much, what about the superfamily could be on the same input order as well? ( ERV , ERV-MaLR..etc)

Comment: my question could be stupid for R users but kindly im new user, one more question if I want to add a space in the species name, how can that be, I have tried it but error occurs it counted it as different elements

Comment: I identified a major error in my code, you need to define the "level = " not "Labels = ". I have rectified this in the current code, but be sure to reimplement the code!

Comment: The reason you're unable to get spaces in the species name is becasue you're directly feeding information into it with read.table().

If you want to get spaces in, you could either:
a) create a .csv file or any othe table-file and read from them with a more stern structure, or

b) change the values after loading them. The easiest way to do this is to change the column names in data before gathering everything into data_long. just pass a vector of strings into colnames(data)[2:5]

Comment: Dear jarn I been trying your info since then, I have created excel sheet and read the table from there, but failed, would you please add the line you mentioned is easy here